# Para que servem os ttys?

Tags: linux

Uso o Fedora 23 e `CTRL + ALT + F1` até o `CTRL + ALT + F6` vou acessando estes terminais, somente preciso utilizá-los quando o modo gráfico trava e preciso reiniciar o gnome e tenho a definição de que estes *ttys* são terminais sem modo gráfico. 
Qual a utilidade destes   *ttys* e por que existem tantos? No meu caso, o Fedora já é "bootado" no *tty2* e no *tty1* existe um outro modo gráfico para fazer login, existe alguma finalidade nisto ou é apenas um default ser inicializado neste *tty2* (nunca reparei isto em outras distros)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Qual a utilidade destes ttys e por que existem tantos?

O `tty` ([**T**ele **TY**pe Writer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprinter)) é um driver que conecta um dispositivo
físico (ex: teclado, modem, impressora) ao [núcleo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)) do sistema operacional.

É utilizado, por exemplo, para que mais usuários possam utilizar a mesma CPU
ou para o controle de [tarefas (ou *jobs*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_(Unix)).

Através de um terminal você pode controlar outros processos (ex: alterar a prioridade, o estado, ou "matar" um processo) que estão utilizando outros terminais.

O exemplo mencionado na pergunta é um controle de processo:

> ... quando o modo gráfico trava e preciso reiniciar o gnome ...

O modo gráfico (normalmente conectado ao **tty7**) "travou" e através de um outro terminal, você consegue eliminar ou reiniciar esse processo.

O número de **6** terminais texto (`tty1` ao `tty6`) foi definido e não tem uma razão determinada.

Apesar do baixo consumo de memória do driver **tty** (ex: de 8kb a 48kb por terminal), você pode alterar o número de terminais físicos no arquivo [inittab](http://www.manpages.info/linux/inittab.5.html) ou [ttys](http://www.manpages.info/freebsd/ttys.5.html) (é necessário consultar a documentação, pois depende do sistema operacional).

*Antes de alterar, é recomendável fazer um backup do sistema.*

Exemplo de um trecho do arquivo `inittab` para um sistema [Debian](https://www.debian.org/):

```
# /sbin/getty invocations for the runlevels.
#
# The "id" field MUST be the same as the last
# characters of the device (after "tty").
#
# Format:
#  <id>:<runlevels>:<action>:<process>
#
# Note that on most Debian systems tty7 is used by the X Window System,
# so if you want to add more getty's go ahead but skip tty7 if you run X.
#
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty1
2:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty2
3:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty3
4:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty4
5:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty5
6:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty6

# Example how to put a getty on a serial line (for a terminal)
#
#T0:23:respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyS0 9600 vt100
#T1:23:respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyS1 9600 vt100

# Example how to put a getty on a modem line.
#
#T3:23:respawn:/sbin/mgetty -x0 -s 57600 ttyS3
```

---

Referências históricas e técnicas:

[The TTY demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/)

[POSIX terminal interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_terminal_interface)

[Linux Internals - Simone Demblon & Sebastian Spitzner - Terminal Emulation](http://freeloaderlinux.sourceforge.net/internals-all.html#d0e1565)

[Computer terminal explained](http://everything.explained.today/Computer_terminal/)

[The Terminal and Job Control](http://www.usna.edu/Users/cs/aviv/classes/ic221/s14/lec/13/lec.html)

[The Evolution of the Unix Time-sharing System](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/hist.html)

[Seventh Edition Unix terminal interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seventh_Edition_Unix_terminal_interface)

[Origins and History of Unix, 1969-1995](http://www.catb.org/esr/writings/taoup/html/ch02s01.html)